# sIFR3 h2 span color

Tags: sifr

I wanted to add this to my previous question, sorry about this Mark.

I'm trying to display span in different colors and font weight, tried a bunch of combinations.

< h2 >title< span > different color < / span>< / h2 >

sIFR.replace(gotham, {
  selector: 'h2',
  css: [
      '.sIFR-root { font-size:24px; color:#4a5659; font-family : Gotham Bold;  letter-spacing:-2; margin: 0 !important; margin-bottom:0;}' ,
       'span{ background-color: #ffffff; color: #993333; font-family : Gotham Light;}'
      ]

,filters: {
        DropShadow: {
           distance: 1
          ,color: '#FFFFFF'
          ,strength: 2
          ,alpha: .5
          ,blurX: 0
          ,blurY: 0

```
    }
  }
```

,wmode: 'transparent'

});

Answer (score 0):

Flash doesn't let you select `span` elements by using a `span` selector (yes! really!). Give it a class and use that instead.

You can't specify different background colors within the sIFR text.

Comment: thanks mark, I actually added a class to it, but left it as spna.light once i removed the span and left .light, all was good

Once again thank you very much.